# mysql-server apt-get install failing

Tags: apt, virtualbox, mysql

I am trying to install mysql-server on a fresh copy of ubuntu/trusty64 (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS). I am using vagrant/virtualbox. I ssh into the box and run the commands below. You can easily replicate this yourself. I have googled around and found many solutions, but none of them are working. The only thing I have managed to do to get around this is to use a different distribution (puphpet/debian75-x64 - Debian GNU/Linux 7.9 (wheezy)).

```
sudo apt-get update
.
.
.

sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18
  libterm-readkey-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common
  mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
Suggested packages:
  libclone-perl libmldbm-perl libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl
  libsql-statement-perl libipc-sharedcache-perl tinyca mailx
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libaio1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libhtml-template-perl libmysqlclient18
  libterm-readkey-perl mysql-client-5.5 mysql-client-core-5.5 mysql-common
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5
0 upgraded, 12 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
Need to get 9072 kB of archives.
After this operation, 96.7 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libaio1 amd64 0.3.109-4 [6364 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main mysql-common all 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 [14.1 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main libmysqlclient18 amd64 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 [597 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libdbi-perl amd64 1.630-1 [879 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libdbd-mysql-perl amd64 4.025-1 [99.3 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libterm-readkey-perl amd64 2.31-1 [27.4 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main mysql-client-core-5.5 amd64 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 [706 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main mysql-client-5.5 amd64 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 [1461 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main mysql-server-core-5.5 amd64 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 [3223 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main mysql-server-5.5 amd64 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 [1981 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libhtml-template-perl all 2.95-1 [65.5 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main mysql-server all 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 [12.4 kB]
Fetched 9072 kB in 12s (738 kB/s)
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Preconfiguring packages ...
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Selecting previously unselected package libaio1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 61004 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libaio1_0.3.109-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libaio1:amd64 (0.3.109-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmysqlclient18:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libmysqlclient18_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbi-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libdbi-perl_1.630-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdbi-perl (1.630-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdbd-mysql-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libdbd-mysql-perl_4.025-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdbd-mysql-perl (4.025-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libterm-readkey-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libterm-readkey-perl_2.31-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libterm-readkey-perl (2.31-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-5.5.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-core-5.5_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-5.5.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-client-5.5_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-5.5.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-core-5.5_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-5.5.
(Reading database ... 61367 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.5_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_amd64.deb ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Unpacking mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-template-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../libhtml-template-perl_2.95-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (2.95-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server_5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libaio1:amd64 (0.3.109-4) ...
Setting up libmysqlclient18:amd64 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Setting up libdbi-perl (1.630-1) ...
Setting up libdbd-mysql-perl (4.025-1) ...
Setting up libterm-readkey-perl (2.31-1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Setting up mysql-client-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Setting up mysql-server-core-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.95-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This looks to be a problem with the ubuntu distribution or am I doing something wrong?

**[UPDATE]**

Output from running `locale`

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

**[UPDATED]**

Error after updating locale.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 52 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up mysql-server-5.5 (5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) ...
mysql stop/waiting
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please run _sudo locale_  command and share output here.

Answer (score 0):

Add the code in the file */etc/environment*

```
LC_ALL="en_GB.utf8"
```

Save and reboot the System.

Or 
Try below:

```
  sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

  Generating locales...
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
  Generation complete.
```

Comment: The above generates the following error on boot. `-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (en_GB.utf8)` I think it's the casing. I changed it to `en_US.UTF-8`. This resolved the locale issue, but I am still getting errors at the end.